# JavaScript countdown timer for every Monday, Wednesday and Friday at 2000 hrs

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create a countdown timer for every Monday, Wednesday and Friday at 2000 hours in JavaScript.
Countdown is working till 2000 hours but after that its not working and also I can't figure out how to switch week i.e. Friday to switch next Monday as there are 3 days count and normal in week there are two days and also I don't want to show days.

I want to convert days into hours and my UI is like 47h 59m 50s this.

I would be grateful if anyone can figure out how to create this countdown.

```js
const gameCountdown = setInterval(function() {
  var gameDay;
  var currentDateTime = new Date();
  var currentDay = currentDateTime.getDay();
  var currentTime = currentDateTime.getTime();
  var gameTime = new Date(currentDateTime.getFullYear(), currentDateTime.getMonth(), currentDateTime.getDate(), 20, 0, 0); // current day 8pm
  var gameDay = (currentDay % 2 === 0) ? currentDay + 1 : currentDay;
  if ((currentDay === gameDay) && (gameTime.getHours() >= 20)) {
    gameTime = currentDateTime.setDate(currentDateTime.getDate() + 2);
  }
  var countdownTime = gameTime.getTime();
  var difference = parseInt((countdownTime - currentTime));
  if (difference > 0) {

    var hours = Math.floor((difference / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    var mins = Math.floor((difference / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
    var sec = Math.floor((difference / 1000) % 60);
    document.querySelector('#hours').innerHTML = hours + 'h';
    document.querySelector('#min').innerHTML = mins + 'm';
    document.querySelector('#sec').innerHTML = sec + 's';
  } else {

    var hours = Math.floor((difference / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    var mins = Math.floor((difference / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
    var sec = Math.floor((difference / 1000) % 60);
    document.querySelector('#hours').innerHTML = hours + 'h';
    document.querySelector('#min').innerHTML = mins + 'm';
    document.querySelector('#sec').innerHTML = sec + 's';

  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="hours"></span>
<span id="min"></span>
<span id="sec"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```js
const getGameTime = (currentTime) => {
  let gameDate = new Date(currentTime)
  let offset = 0;
  if (gameDate.getHours() >= 20) {
    offset += gameDay === 5 ? 3 :  // Friday after 20:00
                              1; // any other day
  }
  gameDate.setDate(gameDate.getDate() + offset);  
  let gameDay = gameDate.getDay();
  offset = 0;
  if (gameDay === 0) offset += 1; // Sunday
  else if (gameDay === 2 || gameDay === 4) offset += 1; // Tuesday or Thursday
  else if (gameDay === 6) offset += 2; // Saturday
  gameDate.setDate(gameDate.getDate() + offset);  
  gameDate.setHours(20, 0, 0);
  return gameDate.getTime();
}

const gameCountdown = setInterval(function() {
  var gameDay;
  var currentDateTime = new Date();
  var currentDay = currentDateTime.getDay();
  var currentTime = currentDateTime.getTime();
  var countdownTime = getGameTime(currentTime);
  var difference = parseInt((countdownTime - currentTime));
  var hours = Math.floor((difference / (1000 * 60 * 60)));
  var mins = Math.floor((difference / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
  var sec = Math.floor((difference / 1000) % 60);
  document.querySelector('#hours').innerHTML = hours + 'h';
  document.querySelector('#min').innerHTML = mins + 'm';
  document.querySelector('#sec').innerHTML = sec + 's';


}, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="hours"></span>
<span id="min"></span>
<span id="sec"></span>
```

Comment: as today is Thursday, countdown showing remaining time till today at 2000 hrs, it should show Friday at 2000 hrs and after that it should move to coming Monday at 2000 hrs, can you please modify this.

Comment: Hmm, complicated. See update - not as elegant as I had hoped